# SSIS Connection not found in package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm kind of new to SSIS programming, and I'm having some problems deploying an SSIS package.

This package runs correctly on my PC, does everything it needs to do ... but when I deploy it cannot find the connection strings.

Here is the error:

> Code: 0xC001000E  Source:  Description: The connection
> "{DA7CD38D-F6AA-4B06-8014-58BEE5684364}" is not found.  This error is
> thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element
> is not found.  End Error
>
> Error: 2012-08-09 00:21:06.25  Code: 0xC001000E  Source: Package
> Description: The connection "{DA7CD38D-F6AA-4B06-8014-58BEE5684364}"
> is not found.  This error is thrown by Connections collection when the
> specific connection element is not found.  End Error
>
> Error: 2012-08-09 00:21:06.25  Code: 0xC001000E  Source: Package
> Description: The connection "{DA7CD38D-F6AA-4B06-8014-58BEE5684364}"
> is not found.  This error is thrown by Connections collection when the
> specific connection element is not found.  End Error
>
> Error: 2012-08-09 00:21:06.25  Code: 0xC00291EB  Source: Execute SQL
> Task Execute SQL Task  Description: Connection manager
> "{DA7CD38D-F6AA-4B06-8014-58BEE5684364}" does not exist.  End Error
>
> Error: 2012-08-09 00:21:06.25  Code: 0xC0024107  Source: Execute SQL
> Task  Description: There were errors during task validation.  End
> Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
> Started: 00:21:04 Finished: 00:21:06 Elapsed: 1.888 seconds.  The
> package execution failed. The step failed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that your ssis package is pointing to some other connection which might have been `deleted` or `renamed` .Try opening the SSIS compoenents and point to the correct connection which are there in your connection manager .

It happens when we copy the SSIS package components to create a new package or because of renaming the connections or there may be still components which are using the old connection defined in you xml config file( In your case try checking the Execute SQL Task which is throwing error ) .If you are using XML for configuration try deploying the new one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get there?i tried before opening(after removing the paw so it wouldnt decode the package) but i can't find the connections, i looked for dts:connection but nothing. i will try again, but can u tell me if i'm doing something worng. thanksin advance for your help :)

Comment: and i also tried to create a package only with the a simple sql task, that changes one field from 1 to 0, and it gave me the same error :(

Comment: R u running the package from BIDS or using sql agent ? R u using a XML configuration for passing the connection string to the package ?

Comment: i'm using sql agent; for the connection string i defined it in my package in the visual studio, and then changed the name of the server to the machine name.
the connections are on the package xml. can this be a problem?

Comment: to me more specific what i do with the connections is:
i have 2 machines, the development and the production. i didmy package in the development, and i created the data sources there and they work with the bd from the development. then before sending the package to the production server, i change the name of the server in the connection string and i build the dtsx again.

Comment: It seems to me that while running the package from sql agent it is not pointing to correct xml file .

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/8bf836c8-bc64-44e0-81f6-621863ae6552/.Check the above article . In short it states that you open all your ssis compoenents verify it whether its pointing to correct connection and then in BIDS open select configuration which points to the XML file and re select all the connections and variables

Comment: After changing build your solution and then open XML file which you need to deploy to production .Change the connection string not the connection string names

Comment: it's an idea instead of changing in the visual studio change it in the xml i will try and i will let u know :)

Comment: i see only one problem with you solution, i can't encript the package, and so it will not work

Comment: unfoutunatly your solution doesnt work, as the package is encrypted :(

Comment: So basic. I had a disabled component which had a bad reference to an ftp connection manager

Answer (score 32):

I'm a little late to the party, but I ran across this thread while experiencing the same errors and found a different resolution.

When creating an SSIS 2012 package, in the Solution Explorer window you will see the Connection Managers folder at the project level. This seems like the most logical place to create a connection, and should be used when creating a connection that can be used by any package in the project. It is included at the project level, and not the package level.

When running my dtsx package using dtexec, I received the same errors shown above. This is because the connection is not included in the package (just the project). My solution was to go into the package designer, and then in the Connection Manager window, right click the project level connection (which is shown using the "(project)" prefix) and choose "Convert to Package Connection". This will embed the connection in the actual dtsx package. This alleviated my problem.

Comment: Had the same issues, and thought it might be the connection manager and the project level connections (since it was only the output connections that failed and they WERE project level).  Doing this resolved it for me.

Comment: I image this works, but it is an absurd solution. Converting the project connection to a package connection makes it inaccessible to all the other packages using it. It seems the project level connection only works at design time.

Comment: I've just come across the same issue... which chump decided this was a good way to design it - project level connections that can't be used via dtexec... there must be a way to point to a reusable connection??

Comment: Don't quite understand what "Package Connection" do you mean? Here's my DTSX package opened in BIDS: http://prntscr.com/bw146y

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. this was the solution i needed. i am using SQL 2017/Visual Studio 2017. Same issue. The solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for posting this issue.

One resolution: open the package in XML form through windows explorer, locate the GUID for the connection manager that cant be found. In my case, it was a bonked EventHandler connection that was corrupted.  This same connection manager was used in the control flow but somehow was not corrupted there, so it was not obvious to the user via the UI. Since the XML pointed to an event handler connection manager, I opened the event handler tab in the UI and it immediately displayed the wonderful RED X on the source and targets that were referencing the corrupted connection manager ID. I repointed it to the correct manager, rebuilt the pkg and saved. Good to go.

The key was opening the pkg in XML format and locating the GUID in the code to see where it was failing. If I was not able to find a valid reference to it in the UI, I was going to either rename the XML connection to another known GUID within the XML and then go into the UI and repoint it again, or delete it altogether.

Good luck.

Comment: It was my problem also ;) after a lot of research and trys i was able to fix it :o

Answer (score 4):

This seems to also happen when you use the new SSIS 2012 "Shared Connection Manager" concept where the connection managers are not defined within your package but the Visual Studio project and just get referenced in the package. Executing it via SQL Agent or DTEXEC yields the same error message.

I haven't found a solution for that yet but would love to get some feedback if anybody experienced it before.

Comment: what i did was, i reinstalled the sql server on my end and renamed to respond as localhost.

Comment: @Roberto Andrade were you able to find a work around?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: I believe what I ended up doing to work around it was deploying the SSIS packages/project into the SQL SSIS Catalog and running them from there instead of from an external executable. 

You can do that creating an SSIS Catalog db in SQL and then in VS right-clicking the project and choosing Deploy and picking the right server/catalog and path you want the project to live under. Then you can either configure a SQL Agent job to run the package from the catalog or trigger executions manually. 

This also helps with execution logs by using the built in SSRS reports instead of the ugly Agent log.

Answer (score 4):

The previous remarks about deleting or removing a connection are absolutely a possibility.  But you can also get this error when you attempt to invoke a package that uses project level connections (instead of package level connections).

If you are using project level connections and still want to use dtexec, never fear there is a way.  I would not recommend converting them to package level connections (assuming you created them as project level connections for a good reason).

You will need to deploy your SSIS project.  Your SSIS server will need to have a catalog created (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509.aspx).  Once you have the catalog, in your SSIS project select Project->Deploy and follow the wizard.  The result will be a *.ispac file generated in your SSIS solution folder/bin/Development

Now for the money command, instead of invoking your package with a simple:
dtexec.exe /f "package.dtsx"

instead call it this way:
dtexec.exe /project "<...>/project.ispac" /package "<...>/package.dtsx"

The ispac file has the project level connection info that is needed to execute your package and you should be set!

Answer (score 3):

In my case i found out that the problem was a Log Provider previously configured point to an old connection not used anymore. To solve the problem click the Package Explorer Tab then click Log Providers and delete the outdated Log Provider. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: It sure helped me to find what was wrong. I also looked into the xml file (.dtsx) of the package and searched for the connection identifier (from the message "connection is not found", like B23A7735-95AB-.....). There I found it was a log provider connection I previously deleted. After deleting the log provider itself, the package ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to solve this problem was simple.
I had to rename my SQL Server so that it would respond to the (localhos) tag.
After that i changed all the connections on the SSIS and i rebuild the solution...it worked.
hope it helps you

Comment: The problem at hand here is not about the hostname being unreachable or some other networking/name resolution issue but finding the reference to the Connection Manager defined within the Visual Studio solution/project/package.

Answer (score 0):

Package works fine on Friday, check in to TFS and go home. Open it on Monday, getting errors everywhere. "connection manager variable $project._connectionstring was not found in the variables collection".

I rtclick-edit the connection and test connectivity, works no prob;em. The ConnMnger is in the Connection Managers list in the solution.  When open the TARGET object connected to this connection manager, and click on MAPPINGS, the error above pops up. There is no reference to connection manager variables anywhere in the mapping.

Turns out, to correct this you must right click on the connection manager in the Connection Manager window and choose PARAMETERIZE. Fill in the options as necessar -

PROPERTY: ConnectionString
Use Exisgint Parameter: $Project::ConnMgrName_ConnectionString
  OR
Create New PArameter: follow the options

Once this connection manager is parameterized, everything works. Even though the Conn Manger existed in the Conn Manger tab, the Conn Mgr is already listed in the Solution Explorer AND worked no problem 2 days prior.

Odd. Whatever. Microsoft being Microsoft. SQL Server being SQL Server. Choose your poison.

Hope this helps the next person save some time.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and niether of the above resoved it. It turns out there was an old sql task that was disabled on the bottom right corner of my ssis that i really had to look for to find. Once i deleted this all was well

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of the event handler task was pointing to old connection which was deleted, deleting the unused event handler task fixed the problem.
I end up opening the package in XML format to understand that the problem is with event handler task!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could solve this in an easier way. I opened the x.dtsConfig archive, and for an unknown reason this archive was not in the standard format, so ssis could not recognize the configurations. Fortunately, I had backed up the archive previously, so I just had to copy it to the original folder, and everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while attempting to open an SSDT 2010/SSIS 2012 project in VS with SSDT 2013.  When it opened the project, it asked to migrate all the packages.  When I allowed it to proceed, every package failed with this error and others.  I found that bypassing the conversion and just opening each package individually, the package is upgraded upon opening, and it converted fine and successfully ran.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my case, the cause was connection was not embedded and  incompatibility of Oracle Client.

**SOLUTION:**

My Environment:SQL SERVER  2014 64bit
Oracle Client 32 bit

1. For include/embed Connection

   - open package
   - right click on connection
   - select "Convert to project" option
2. for SQL SSIS Catalog/Job schedule set the configuration follow steps in picture

   - Right on 'SQL JOB->Step"  or "SSIS Catalog-->Package-->Execute" and select "Properties"
   - Select Configuration-->Advanced tab
   - Checked 32-bit runtime

I tried to post detail step by step pictures, but Stack Overflow does not allow that due to reputation. Hope I later will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

Go to SQL Server Management Studio, Right click on the failing step and select Properties -> Logging -> Remove the Log Provider, and then re-add it

Answer (score 0):

I determined that this problem was a corrupt connection manager by identifying the specific connection that was failing. I'm working in SQL Server 2016 and I have created the SSISDB catalog and I am deploying my projects there.

Here's the short answer. Delete the connection manager and then re-create it with the same name. Make sure the packages using that connection are still wired up correctly and you should be good to go. If you're not sure how to do that, I've included the detailed procedure below.

To identify the corrupt connection, I did the following. In SSMS, I opened the Integration Services Catalogs folder, then the SSISDB folder, then the folder for my solution, and on down until I found my list of packages for that project.

By right clicking the package that failed, going to reports>standard reports>all executions, selecting the last execution, and viewing the "All Messages" report I was able to isolate which connection was failing. In my case, the connection manager to my destination. I simply deleted the connection manager and then recreated a new connection manager with the same name.

Subsequently, I went into my package, opened the data flow, found that some of my destinations had lit up with the red X. I opened the destination, re-selected the correct connection name, re-selected the target table, and checked the mappings were still correct. I had six destinations and only three had the red X but I clicked all of them and made sure they were still configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I generally find that when SSIS seems to be irrationally complaining about an apparently good connection, it is because I am trying to define the Connection directly using a package variable rather than via a Connection Manager. Example: today I had a Web Service Task where I made the mistake of directly creating an Expression defining its "Connection" property in terms of a package variable that contained the URL of the web service. Note however that a Connection is not the same thing as a ConnectionString! So when I looked at the task, it looked for all the world like it had everything valid, because it displayed a perfectly valid URL as the "Connection". The problem is that the Connection cannot be a string; it must be a Connection Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The connection value in the job seems to be case sensitive.

Comment: This might be better as a comment... Else, please consider expanding on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For package developed in Visual Studio 2015, I found i must supply a value for the parameter (which would be the case when you deploy or run on different server) which sets the connection manager's connection string instead of using the design time value.
This will suppress the error message. I think this could be a bug.

```
dtexec /project c:\mypath\ETL.ispac /package mypackage.dtsx /SET \Package.Variables[$Project::myParameterName];"myValueForTheParameter"
```

I tested this without or without parameterize the connection string, which is at the project level. The result was the same: i.e. I have to set the value for the parameter even thought it was not used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I use project level connection managers and my packages run correctly in SSDT but when I deployed them and execute them through a job with sql server agent, I get "Connection not found" errors.

So I deploy the project and then the problem was solved, when you use project level connection managers but just deploy a single package from that project, and you call package through sql server agent, it could not recognize your connection managers so you should determine package level connection managers or you should first deploy your project.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me: 
SSIS-package not created by me started at some point behaving unexpectedly, like giving that Connection not found -error and my task was to fix it though.
When I looked at Job Step Properties under SQL Agent jobs, it showed no Configurations in use and Data sources were exact they should be. But, error message pointed to something different. Then I opened .dtsx file in question and noticed that there IS package conf. set and in that package conf. file is connection name set wrong. So my advice is to compare .dtsx and .dtsConfig -files side by side.