# Project Connection Managers in SSIS

Tags: ssis, connection

When I try to run my Package from SQL Server Management Studio(I've got it in Stored Packages in Integration Services Service) or just by double clicking package file, I get an error:
Connection Manager not found.

If I make connection manager as package instead of project It runs fine.
I found this problem on google but didn't find solution.

I haven't deploy my package to ssisdb yet so I don't know if it's working in that case.

Comment: which version of SSIS you are using?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _If I make connection manager as package instead of project_. If this is explained further in some other link, please provide a reference to it.

Comment: Project Connection Manager is visible to every package I created. SSIS shows it in Solution Explorer under Connection Managers. Package connection manager is visible only to package in which I created it. I found similar topic which was not solved. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874722/ssis-connection-not-found-in-package

"This seems to also happen when you use the new SSIS 2012 "Shared Connection Manager" concept where the connection managers are not defined within your package but the Visual Studio project and just get referenced in the package...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is common problem in SSIS. If you deploy your application - project (scope project- instead of package) connection managers will be visible and package will work. But if you want to run a package by double clicking in folder - you can't use project connection managers.