# I get a failure message when i try to run a ssis package from C# windows app..

Tags: c#, windows, ssis

The failure message is : description = "The runtime connection manager with the ID \"{09A00ED5-21CC-48E4-A7CC-90CC3DC13B52}\" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager collection has a connection manager with that ID.\r\n"  description = "Lookup failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801B.\r\n"  description = "One or more component failed validation.\r\n......

Comment: Look through your package xml and identify which connection manager this is. Is this SQL 2012 and later and if so which deployment model (package or project?)

Comment: Its a package which I deployed in SQL server 2012. How can i view the package xml ?

Comment: do you know if it is a project deployment or a package deployment? is it deployed to the SSIS catalog? How many connection managers does the package have? are they project or package level connection managers?

Comment: Has this package just stopped working or has it never worked? does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874722/ssis-connection-not-found-in-package

Comment: Its a package deployment.. It has 3 connection managers. All the connection managers are global ones (Project level connection managers).

Comment: It worked if I run in the BI tool but is not working if I run via c# code

Answer (score 0):

Restart both ends of the equation starting with the App side. It appears you have an invalid end point either on the Windows App side or on the SSIS server side. I have seen this when someone restarts SQL server, or re-compiles / re-deploys the SSIS package. And, make sure the SSIS package is in a valid state.

Comment: Thanks.. I ll check this out. Shall I try executing the package by creating an SQL server job..

Comment: I think create a SQL Job would be a good way to test whether a connection and package are both viable.

let me know if it works out.

Comment: I tried running it by importing the package to SQL but it gets failed with the same error messages. Is this a problem with a liscence aggrement or Connection manager issues ? If so is there any way to resolve this ?

Comment: What about the credentials? Do you know if the package was saved with, or without, credentials? And, is the package running successfully anywhere you can get a valid export of it?

Comment: I didnt give any credentials to run the package.It was on my laptop. the package runs successfully when i run it from BI tool but fails when i call it from the C# CODE or when i try running it from SQL server studio.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are trying to run a remote SSIS package from a client. It would be helpful to see the code you are using. Here is an article on doing this from c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355(v=sql.110).aspx.

And, to reiterate my previous concern around the portability of SSIS packages from machine to machine. If you don't save the SSIS package without credentials, you can run into security/config issues trying to install and run the package on another machine that doesn't have access to those credentials. Here is an older reference http://zarez.net/?p=155.