# SSIS Connection Manager Does Not Exist

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl

I have created a database through a task script in SSIS.  When I later try to connect to that database through the Connection Manager I am told that the Connection Manager does not exist.  The database is there in the server.

How can I establish the connection to the database to load the data after I've created a new DB in the script?

[image: error-0]
[image: error-1]

> **Error:** The connection "Data Source=..;Initial Catalog=8888888;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

[image: Control Workflow]

From the Microsoft Forums [The connection "" is not found from..](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2af470ac-d76d-4162-849f-a5e0411aa053/the-connection-quotquot-is-not-found-this-error-is-thrown-by-connections-collection-when-the?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Similar question: [SSIS Connection not found in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874722/ssis-connection-not-found-in-package)

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the DataFlow and ControlFlow? Basically I think it's quite bad practive to create a DB from SSIS and then populate it with Data in the same step... however: I would suggest to define a String Variable which will contain the Connectstring (the one you posted) and then create a new ConnectionManager in your population package on which you put an Expression in order to use this Stringvariable as Connectionstring. This Connectionmanager can then be used within your package.

Comment: @Tyron78 This is simply a matter of configuring the connection string and variables correctly?  What steps would you take to create a DB and populate with Data?

Comment: No, you will additionally need a ConnectionManager. It's an object in your project (assuming you are working in a project...) which you can add. This ConnectionManager can then be modified in order to not use a static connectionstring but to use a variable instead. This string variable as you already mentioned has then to be populated with the correct string. This can be done within your script task.

Comment: So, did you succeed in creating the connection manager? Otherwise I'll try to support you...

Comment: @Tyron78 Yes, we were able to establish a dynamic connection through the connection manager.  The flat files are now loading to the database.

Comment: @Tyron78 If you post your second comment as answer I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a ConnectionManager. It's an object in your project (assuming you are working in a project...) which you can add. This ConnectionManager can then be modified in order to not use a static connectionstring but to use a variable instead. This string variable as you already mentioned has then to be populated with the correct string. This can be done within your script task