# Azure Data Factory -SSIS Exec - The connection manager SMTP is not found

Tags: azure-data-factory, ssis-2008

I am trying to migrate packages created with visual studio 2008 to Azure Data factory. I had some issues creating the Azure SSIS integrated runtime due to not having a server. (I was able to create the runtime without creating the SSISDB to deploy packages to). I thought I could execute packages in a pipeline without it. Now I am trying to create a simple pipeline to execute the .dtsx and it is failing for the connection managers not being recognized.

I had some permissions issues with the Azure SQL server that the package was writing to. I fixed that by hardcoding the SQL server auth password in the connection string and saving the package with save sensitive with password. I am running the .dtsx from a file share in BLOB but the pipeline is failing as it doesn't recognize the SMTP connection manager that the package uses to notify of failure/success. I tried adding the connection manager in the exec ssis step.

Scope=Package; Name=SMTP Connection Manager; Property=ConnectionString; Value=ConnString..

Pipeline is still failing.

I've noticed some tutorials where if you deploy to a SSISDB the connection managers will appear in the tab to select what values you want.

How can I get the connection manager to be recognize and is it possible to exec a .dtsx in ADF without deploying? Seems I should since there is an execute from file share option.

Comment: _I was able to create the runtime without creating the SSISDB to deploy packages to_  _is it possible to exec a .dtsx in ADF without deploying?_ Is it actually your requirement to not use SSISDB? I expect all of this will be _much_ easier if you follow standard practice rather than trying to execute from a file. I don't even know how you would implement global connection managers if running from a file

Comment: We use a file system for our on-premise jobs. Azure has the file system as an option to deploy...

Comment: Does the file system approach work for you on prem? Are you using shared connection managers? I suspect it doesn't support shared connection managers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982661/1690193 It's been a very long time since I worked in SSIS